# Why is `purrr::flatten` so slow?

Tags: r, dataframe, purrr

Trying to flatten a list of matrices into single `data.frame` in `R`.
`purrr:flatten` would be an obvious choice but it is really slow.
In this simple example below `flatten` is ca. 50 times slower on RStudio Server and 10 times slower on R terminal than the alternative using `reduce(full_join)`!
Why is that?
Is there a way around it?

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
library(tibble)
start_time = Sys.time()
rerun(10, as_tibble(matrix(rnorm(36),nrow=6))) %>% 
  flatten_dfc() # alternatively map_dfc(., bind_cols)
end_time = Sys.time()
end_time - start_time # 9.2 sec

start_time = Sys.time()
rerun(10, rowid_to_column(as_tibble(matrix(rnorm(36),nrow=6)))) %>% 
  reduce(full_join, by="rowid", suffix = c(".1", ".2"))
end_time = Sys.time()
end_time - start_time # 0.2 sec
```

Comment: What versions are you using? With tibble_3.1.6 purrr_0.3.4  dplyr_1.0.7 I'm getting 0.13 seconds for the first block

Comment: Almost the same, except that I have dplyr_1.08.
See my edit. Seems particularly bad on RStudio Server but also on my local terminal I'm getting a X10 difference in speed

Comment: Also it looks like simply calling `bind_cols()` could work just as well

Comment: based on profvis output, name repair is what takes all that time

Comment: similar ways to do the same thing: `c = invoke(cbind, your_list);
  d = do.call(cbind, your_list);
  e = lift(cbind)(your_list);
  f = lift_dv(cbind)(your_list);
  g = lift_dl(cbind)(your_list);
  h = bind_cols(your_list);
  i = map_dfc(your_list, identity); ....`

Comment: Good call, @user12728748 !
But you cannot pass `.name_repair` to flatten

Comment: If your concern is speed then you can replace `flatten_dfc()` with  `rbindlist()` (from data.table) then setback to data.frame with `setDF()`.